# Are the rules of eclipses (grahaṇa) still valid if the eclipse is not visible from the observers' place?

Tags: scripture, belief, practice, eclipse

There was a recent [Lunar Eclipse](https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/science/lunar-eclipse-2021-live-updates-7330168/) (Chandra Grahaṇa) - the first for the year 2021.

> The full eclipse began at 11.11 am UTC, which was around 4.41 pm IST. **But the total lunar eclipse was not visible in India.**

Whenever an eclipse is said to be "visible" in a certain place, it's a practice for the people of that area to follow all the "rules and protocols" of a *sūtaka* and other practices. Like Temples closing their doors, people not going out throughout the eclipse  duration, and not consuming food, etc..

However, many a times, the eclipse is not even visible in several areas. Like this eclipse cited above.  This eclipse wasn't observable from India.

Question - Does the same "rules and protocols" apply to such kind of eclipses too, which are not visible from an "observer's place"? Please give either scripturally sourced answer or the views of "authoritative personalities".

Comment: As a first piece information: If eclipse is not visible, then rules are not to be followed. (Idk where it comes from, most panchang or calanders mention it)

Comment: Yes @Proxy, I too have read it. However, I also have heard several "TV astrologers" saying opposite (some say few rules are still valid; some say all rules are still valid)

Comment: Temples in South India are usually not closed if eclipse is not visible and rules too not followed, although need to check source for this.

Comment: OH that's interesting @TheDestroyer. In the North though, AFAIK, all temples generally close their doors (*kapāṭa*) for the eclipse duration. Also, other practices (like semi-fasting, staying indoors) are also invariably followed by many

Comment: i too know from experience - if it's not visible, it's not followed, at least in south india. maybe only the temples where it was visible closed in north india ?

Comment: Well, @mar , if it's visible in North, it'll be visible throughout India. In North, some temples do follow all the sūtaka rules, for "non-observable" eclipses too, like this Lunar Eclipse.

Comment: *"if it's visible in North, it'll be visible throughout India."* - huh? No. here is visibility chart for recent lunar eclipse - https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4906. partial eclipse visible in NE india, a bit of sikkim, westbengal. you could have eastern india in path of eclipse but not western.

Comment: My bad with wrong words @mar. What I meant is,  since we were talking about the 'North-South theological practices difference', thus, *"if it's Visible in the North India, mostly very good chances exists that even South India will see it".* Of course, some far-off parts of West or North-east might be exceptions due to vast longitudinal and latitudinal stretches of Indian subcontinent.

Comment: They ain't valid. — Vishnottara Purana.