# Why are only temples of Lord Shiva open,even during eclipse?

Tags: shiva, temple, navagraha, eclipse

The following sentence was seen in Quora(If the reader wants,I can give the link)

“**Only Lord Shiva temples kept open During Solar , moon Eclipse, beacause nothing can effect lord Shiva , beacause lord Shiva is beyond everything . Navagrahas worship only lord Shiva .others temples kept closed during Eclipse**

Is this true?Please give scripture references,if possible. (Although there are similar answers,they don’t give scripture references/answer doesn’t explain **why**)

Comment: what's source? Only temples that have relationship with Rahu Ketu are not closed (like Srikalahasti temple) but all other Shiva temples are closed.

Comment: @The Destroyer: https://qr.ae/pGYgGi

Comment: No sir. Shiva temples are closed during eclipse.

Comment: Is the presence of Navagrahas at Shiva temples a reason for the claim?

Comment: All temples in North are closed during an eclipse. See [this question and their comments](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46574/are-the-rules-of-eclipses-grahan%cc%a3a-still-valid-if-the-eclipse-is-not-visible-f)